# Why is redirect resetting my object?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I made a frontend extension with Extbase in TYPO3 6.2 and while redirecting in my controller I'm loosing changes I've made to my object.
I wonder if this is intended and why?

Here I see the change I've made to `appointment` in the `var_dump`.

```
/**
 *
 * @param Domain\Model\Appointment $appointment
 * @return void
 */
public function bookAction(Domain\Model\Appointment $appointment) {
    if ($appointment->getBooked()) {
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($appointment);
        $this->redirect('update', null, null, array('appointment'=>$appointment));
    }
}
```

Then I see the original object before the changes I've made to `appointment` in the `var_dump`.
It seems like the passing of the changed appointment resets it back to its original state...?

```
/**
 * action update
 *
 * @param Domain\Model\Appointment $appointment
 * @return void
 */
public function updateAction(Domain\Model\Appointment $appointment) {
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($appointment);
}
```

Comment: It seems that from your code that you just debug your value and pass same object in redirect, you have to first stored your changes into your object, 

Like if you want to changed anything in your object then you have to use setter menthod of particular property.

Comment: but the changes are already in the object, I'm not debugging a value, I'm debugging the whole object and I can see that it has the correct values I entered in the form that calls bookAction. Could it be that TYPO3 just reloads the object from the repository when redirecting instead of passing the actual object to the redirect function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extbase controllers contain two methods of calling different action within your current action: `redirect()` and `forward()`.

The difference is tiny, but consequences can be huge.

**redirect()** calls a different action via 30x HTTP redirect, so basically it requires complete page reload with restoring (and re-initializing) PHP session, data and objects.

Internally Extbase passes just an object's `id` to a second action, meaning, that in that second action your object is fetched from persistence again. And if the changes were not persisted in previous action, they'll be lost.

**forward()** just terminates the current MVC request and starts a new one without a page reload, meaning that all the session data and not-peristed changes are still available in a second action.

In this case Extbase passes not an `id`, but real object, so the changes are still there.

You can do one of the following:

1. Use `forward()` instead of `redirect()`.
2. Persist changes to db via `PersistenceManager` before calling `redirect()`.
3. Preserve your object changes somehow (e.g. pass not a real instance to `redirect()`, but serialized string and then unserialize it in your second action).

Comment: thank you, perfect answer with many details! :) Very helpful for me!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any code where you actually persist anything. So you need that in your update action

```
$persistenceManager = $this->objectManager->get("TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\PersistenceManager");
$persistenceManager->persistAll();
```

Just changing the object without persisting it won't change anything!